# Interpolation of a CustomStringConvertible failing in a SwiftUI Text view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have roughly something like this and it works (see https://swiftfiddle.com/hu64oaef4fe23e3cqz6fkn44zq):

```swift
import Foundation
struct S : CustomStringConvertible {
  var description : String { "foo" }
}
print(S())  // prints foo
print("interpolated \(S())")
```

But if I try to use the interpolation of the CustomStringConvertible inside a Text view's string, like

```swift
var s : S
...
Text("\(s)")
```

it fails to compile with **No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'**.

Notably, it compiles and works if I use `Text("\(foo.description)")`.  It also works with things like an Int:

```swift
let a = 5
...
Text("\(a)")
```

Any ideas why the direct interpolation for my CustomStringConvertible type does not work?

Edited: grammar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Text.init` you are using requires `some StringProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-9d1g4). `StringProtocol` derives from `CustomStringConvertible`, not the other way around.

```swift
 Text(verbatim: "\(s)")
```

is an option.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense (and using the [verbatim initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(verbatim:)) works, of course).  I am still confused how the StringProtocol comes into the pictrure since interpolation is a language feature, no?

Also, does it make sense to attempt to implement StringProtocol?  It doesn't look trivial.

Comment: Looked a little further into this.

* StringProtocol should not be conformed to by new types (from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Swift/StringProtocol#overview): Do not declare new conformances to StringProtocol. Only the String and Substring types in the standard library are valid conforming types.

* Any CustomStringConvertible can be interpolated like so:

`Text("some text... \(String(describing: S())) and some more text")`

Answer (score 1):

## LocalizedStringResource uses a custom implementation of StringInterpolation, which doesn't support `CustomStringConvertible`.

Here's the solution up top:

```swift
extension LocalizedStringResource.StringInterpolation {
    public mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: CustomStringConvertible) {
        appendInterpolation(String(describing: value))
    }
}
```

The accepted answer works, but for different reasons. See in the description of [Text.init(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-9d1g4): **SwiftUI doesn’t call the init(_:) method when you initialize a text view with a string literal as the input.**

The default `Text` initializer is `init(key:tableName:bundle:comment:)`, where `key` is a `LocalizedStringResource`. `LocalizedStringResource` implements `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` and `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation`, which is why you can initialize a `Text` using a string literal; it's automatically converted to a `LocalizedStringResource`. This is important for localization, as it means you can set up a localization (`"Hello World"="Hallo Welt"`) without needing to change how you instantiate your `Text` views.

However, `LocalizedStringResource` uses a *custom implementation* of `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation` (see [ExpressibleByStringInterpolation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Swift/ExpressibleByStringInterpolation)). This means that `LocalizedStringResource.StringInterpolation` doesn't use `DefaultStringInterpolation`, which *does* support interpolation of `CustomStringConvertible` instances.

To fix this, all you have to do is extend `LocalizedStringResource.StringInterpolation` with a custom `appendInterpolation<T>(_ value: T) where T: CustomStringConvertible`, and voila! This is preferrable to the accepted answer (Use `Text.init(verbatim:)`) as this allows you use interpolation directly, **and** still set up localization for those values later if desired.

Why does the accepted answer work? Because `Text(verbatim:)` initializes a `Text` view **without localization**, thereby avoiding the use of `LocalizedStringResource`.

Comment: Good explanation, thank you!  The initializers part is interesting, I read over them but it's not immediately obvious to me why would the compiler chose one over the other when the parameter is specifically a string literal.

Comment: Thanks! After a bit of digging, I believe that's because `Text.init<S>(_ content: S)` uses [`@_disfavoredOverload`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6e695bf07ccf36f7237ee703ec44691a11b06c12/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md#_disfavoredoverload), which instructs the compiler to choose other initializers over that one. You can force the compiler to choose it by writing `let str = "hello world"; Text(str)`; Command-clicking on the code shows the use of `Text<S>(_ content: S)` with `@_disfavoredOverload`.